# Wrong size of bitwise struct

Tags: android, c++, iphone, struct, ios-simulator

I have bitwise C++ struct:

```
struct MXBodyStateCompact {
    uint8_t angle : 8;
    uint16_t positionX : 16;
    uint16_t positionY : 16;

    void Set(MXBodyState state);
    void GetState(MXBodyState *state);
};
```

It works perfectly on iPhone – 5 bytes per instance. Exactly what I need.

But get a trouble on iOS Simulator and Android. There are allocated 6 bytes per instance. While `angle` is still 1 byte long (according to `sizeof`), it takes 2 bytes in memory:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(*this)
$4 = 6
(gdb) p sizeof(this->angle)
$5 = 1
(gdb) p sizeof(this->positionX)
$6 = 2
(gdb) p sizeof(this->positionY)
$7 = 2
(gdb) p this
$8 = (struct MXBodyStateCompact *) 0x7ee5d035
(gdb) p &this->angle
$9 = (uint8_t *) 0x7ee5d035 "X"
(gdb) p &this->positionX
$10 = (uint16_t *) 0x7ee5d037
(gdb) p &this->positionY
$11 = (uint16_t *) 0x7ee5d039
```

As you can see, there is 2 bytes between the address of `angle` and the address of `positionX`.

Is there any way to force compiler/system to respect size of struct fields? Or need to find some other way how to deal with my binary file? (I use this struct to process data from binary files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__attribute__((packed))` to tell gcc or clang not to insert padding between members of this struct.

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) MXBodyStateCompact {
    uint8_t angle : 8;
    uint16_t positionX : 16;
    uint16_t positionY : 16;

    void Set(MXBodyState state);
    void GetState(MXBodyState *state);
}
```

Also, the `: 8` and `: 16` seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, `:8` and `:16` are unnecessary, if `__attribute__((packed))` is used. But previously `:8` and `:16` made the same effect as this attribute, when compiled for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

check this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Data alignment means putting the data at a memory offset equal to some multiple of the word size, which increases the system's performance due to the way the CPU handles memory. To align the data, it may be necessary to insert some meaningless bytes between the end of the last data structure and the start of the next, which is data structure padding.